# change cursor on ng-change

Tags: css, angularjs

I have a list of input elements (checkboxes) and when it changes a function is called. I could do this by jquery/javascript but I would like it to work with CSS only, how can I do that? Right now the cursor changes when i hovet the inputs and not only when its changed.

```
<li class="cbxList" ng-repeat="column in columns">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="column.checked" ng-change="columnChecked()"> {{column.name}}
      <span class="movedown glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down pull-right" ng-click="grpColumnMoveDown($index)"></span>
      <span class="moveup glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up pull-right" ng-click="grpColumnMoveUp($index)"></span>
</li>
```

css:

```
.cbxList input, ng-change {
cursor: wait;
}
```

Comment: you would need to dynamically apply the cursor to `body` css element..

Comment: maybe ngClass can help you?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I did this through jquery using angularjs broadcast events to tell when to change cursor

Comment: Hey now, this is not an answer, is it?  Your question was maybe not the most detailed, but it is a nice practical question that could have had a good simple answer. A nice match for the SO-format in my book. But this answer is lacking. You even have the solution already, so why not share?

Comment: @ippi The solution I shared is how I solved it. If someone comes up with a better idea of how to solve it I would gladly change the answer